# Reset OpenCL Nvidia Drivers without reboot

Tags: opencl, nvidia

Nvidia drivers for OpenCL become unresponsive after a while (from one day to the next).

When the issue occurs, `clinfo` produces:

```
$ clinfo
clinfo: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1: no version information available (required by clinfo)
Number of platforms  0
```

`nvidia-smi` still functions properly as does the cuda device when using cuda drivers. After a reboot, everything functions properly. I'm also using this device for my display.

Potentially this is related to undocking or hibernating the system.

**Is there a way to reset the drivers without rebooting?
Any way to discover why the driver is unresponsive?**

Answer (score 0):

Reloading the drivers seems to resolve the issue. On Fedora, this can be done with

```
sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm
```